# Algorithm- How to place n-texts on p-bands so that the global accesing time is minimum. Each text has its' own length

Tags: algorithm, greedy

The problem sounds like this, we are given n-texts and they are going to be placed on a p number of tapes/bands(don't really know what's the equivalent in english, but I think you understand what I'm talking about).

In order to read the text situated at a position k on one of the bands, we have to read the texts from positions 1,2,...,k on the certain band. Each text has its' own length.

Now, we have to figure out a way of placing the texts on the p-bands so that we get a global accesing time that is minimum. The global accesing time is calculated by adding all the total accesing times from each band.

The formula for calculating the total accesing time of a band is:

```
n_
 \  [L(T1)+L(T2)+...+L(Ti)]
 /_    
i=1
```

> Now, that little drawing I did is SUM from 1 to n;
>
> L(T i) is the length of T i;
>
> T i is the text situated at position i on the respective band;

Here is an equivalent in "pseudocode" in case it helps:

```
n-number of texts;
Band[n]-array of texts
sum=0, sum2=0; 
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {sum=0;
    for(int j=0;j<=i;j++ )
        sum=sum+Band[j].length;
    sum2=sum2+sum; }
return sum2;
```

Here's an example to clarify the problem:

```
say p is 3, so we get 3 bands
say n is 9, so we get 9 texts and the lengths are : 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,   8,  9, 10 
and they are placed on the bands in the following way:
```

> band-1: 2, 5, 8 -> total accesing time of band-1: 24
>
> band-2: 3, 6, 9 -> total accesing time of band-2: 30
>
> band-3: 4, 7, 10 -> total accesing time of band-3: 36
>
> the global accesing time: 24 + 30 + 36 = 90

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll refer to text position as the number of texts that appear after a specific text in a tape, it also represents how many additional times will the text be read.

Since you are solely interested in the sum of access time there's no real meaning to how are the texts grouped into tapes but what is the position of each text, switching 2 texts in the same position but on different tapes for example won't change the global access time.
Switching 2 texts of different size on different positions will change the time though, generally longer texts should be placed in lower positions (closer to the end)

The algorithm can be greedy, go over the texts from the longest to the shortest and place each text in the last available spot on one of the tapes with the least texts in it, so if for example there are 10 texts and 5 tapes then the longer 5 texts will be in the end of each tape and the shorter 5 texts will be in the beginning of it.

Comment: I don't think that's the best way to go about it, because if you place the longer texts first, then they will be taken into consideration for each iteration, but if you place them last, they will be taken into consideration only once. I think the best way to solve it is kind of the opposite of what you said, place the smaller texts first and the largest ones last.

Comment: Yeah, I wrote to place each text in the tape before the last text, I'll try to make it clearer